# How to deal with a tree structure in terms of collection and model in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, hierarchy

```
treeJSon = {
    "text":"europe",
    "leaf":false,
    "children":[
        {
            "text":"spain",
            "leaf":false,
            "children":[
                {
                    "text":"realmadrid",
                    "leaf":false,
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"ronaldo",
                            "leaf":true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text":"barcelona",
                    "leaf":false,
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"messi",
                            "leaf":true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text":"england",
            "leaf":false,
            "children":[
                {
                    "text":"unknown english",
                    "leaf":true
                },
                {
                    "text":"liverpool",
                    "leaf":false,
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"gerald",
                            "leaf":true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The Json I will be receiving is similar to the above. What is the best approach I need to follow in for displaying a hierarchical model in a tree view.

Comment: Use id and parent_id and flat collection with method which allows you to return a tree.

Comment: Eugene it will be helpful if you provide an example

Comment: Here is an example where flat backbone collection is generated by provided json http://jsfiddle.net/Vswm3/

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene. I will go through your code.

Comment: Hi Eugene, your code was superb ,got an idea how to parse through the json within a collection.  The real situation I am facing here is when I get a json tree I have to create collection only when we click the child nodes. For eg. Root1 > child1 > subchild1. Here I have to display first the root nodes and only on clicking the root node 'Root1' the child list 'child1' should be shown or the child collection should be created. It will be of great help if you can shed some light into this. Thanks in advance